# Node.JS C++ Native Addon read/write file?

Tags: c++, node.js, native, v8, node-webkit

The current problem I am facing with my project is that I do not know how to read/write files from the native node.js addon.

I have to build a type of encryption decryption ( RC6 algorithm ) program. But in order to encrypt files, i should be able to somehow read and write to them from "node-webkit". I am building the .cc file with nw-gyp, and tried multiple possibilities but none worked.

I am building my project with "grunt-node-webkit-builder" and I simply want to read/write one file from the build folder "nw" where nw.exe is located.

The Structure looks like this:

`.webkitbuilds
   .releases
       .nw
          .win
              .nw
                 encrypt.txt
                 ffmpegsumo.dll
                 icudt.dll
                 libEGL.dll
                 libGLESv2.dll
                 nw.exe
                 nw.pak`

How can I read in my c++ native node.js addon that "encrypt.txt" file.

Help ?

Edit:

Is there any way to use libuv with crypto ++ ?

**EDIT 2:**

I have the following code. The moment I execute it, the window freezes.

hello.cc:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace v8;

#define __S_IREAD       0400    /* Read by owner.  */
#define __S_IWRITE      0200    /* Write by owner.  */
#define __S_IEXEC       0100    /* Execute by owner.  */

#define S_IRUSR __S_IREAD       /* Read by owner.  */


uv_loop_t* loop;

uv_fs_t open_req;

void open_cb(uv_fs_t* req);

const char* path = "encrypt.txt";

void open_cb(uv_fs_t* req) {
    int result = req->result;

    if (result == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at opening file: %s\n",
                uv_strerror(uv_last_error(loop)));
    }

    uv_fs_req_cleanup(req);

    printf("Successfully opened file.\n");
}

char *get(v8::Local<v8::Value> value, const char *fallback = "") {
    if (value->IsString()) {
        v8::String::AsciiValue string(value);
        char *str = (char *) malloc(string.length() + 1);
        strcpy(str, *string);
        return str;
    }
    char *str = (char *) malloc(strlen(fallback) + 1);
    strcpy(str, fallback);
    return str;
}


Handle<Value> Encrypt(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

      char* textToEncrypt = get(args[0], "str");
      char* password = get(args[1], "str");

    loop = uv_default_loop();

        int r = uv_fs_open(loop, &open_req, path, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR, open_cb);

        if (r) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error at opening file: %s\n",
                    uv_strerror(uv_last_error(loop)));
        }

        uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

  return scope.Close(String::New("done"));
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("Encrypt"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Encrypt)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(hello, Init)
```

***In Javascript :***

```
var application = require('./js/build/Release/hello');

    var encrypted_data = "";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_encrypt').on('click', function() {

             encrypted_data = application.Encrypt("val","val");
             console.log(encrypted_data);
        })
    });
```

Comment: try `uv_fs_open` + `uv_fs_read`

Comment: Is it possible to use libuv with crypto++ ? I do not know how to use them. A simple example would help a lot.